# React native - Convert HTML to PNG and download Base64

Tags: html, react-native, components, png

I develop a project that able to make a self-graphic image and download it to the computer, but I stack in big problem.

I don't know where is exactly my problem, but it happened when I try to download the image on a different screen.

Suppose that the user make [this graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/degFb.png)

when I try to download it on the 27' screen it's like the image above, On the other hand on the 14' screen is looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hGV5.png).

Edited: another issue, right now I work on 2 screens left 27' and right is the 14', on left screen download the image clearly and when I drag the window (**without change window size**) to another screen (14') it's again downloaded it smaller.

```
const onDownloadImage = () => {
var node = document.getElementById("section");
htmlToImage
  .toPng(node)
  .then(function (base64) {
    let encoded = base64?.split(",");
    setBase64(encoded[1]);
    triggerBase64Download(base64, "My Canvas");
    hideEditElements(false);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error("oops, something went wrong!", error);
  });};
```

the library I used :

[html-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image) to get the elements by id and convert them to base64.

and [react-base64-downloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-base64-downloader) to download the base64 image.

Thanks all !!

Comment: Try React Native View Shots
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-shot

Comment: Your WebView Will Be Wrapped In ViewShot.